# Can't install VMWare Tools on FreeBSD 11.0

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, freebsd

I'm trying to install Vmware tools in FreeBSD 11 but I got this message:

```
guest memory manager failed
```

[image]

I'm using `VMware Workstation 12.5.2`

Gnome is working well but in small screen size

[image]

Is there any solution for that ?

I've already tried this method: [how to install Vmware tools](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vmtools.install.doc%2FGUID-9A1EC217-58F6-4E97-BF50-1C5581B9C55A.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile the module by youself:

1. tail /var/log/messages
   Jan  8 23:10:59 service3 kernel: KLD **vmmemctl.ko**: depends on kernel - not available or version mismatch
2. Execute "Step 7.3 – Compile the vmmemctl module"
   http://www.rhyous.com/2012/05/09/installing-vmware-tools-on-freebsd-9-without-xorg/